# View numbers on Favorites page have the wrong color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bookmarks

[image]

As you can see, the word "views" is highlighted the correct color, but the numbers remain the standard gray.  Shouldn't the numbers be the same color as the word "views"?

I'm using Firefox 34 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after our next production build.